# Is it Possible to use Jackson to convert an Static Class to JSON?

Tags: java, json, class, static, jackson

I was wondering if it possible to convert Statics Classes with Jackson instead Doing a parser by myself. For Example I have the next Static Class:

```
public static class SQL {
    public enum Table {
        CREATE,
        ALTER
    }

    public enum Database {
        CREATE
    }

}
```

And I want to convert to next Json String

```
{
  "SQL" : 
    {
      "Table": 
        {"CREATE": "CREATE", "ALTER": "ALTER"},
        {"CREATE": "CREATE"}
    }
 }
```

This is because I can use this class in Java to create great strings, and I want a similar functionality in Javascript Side.

I tried to use

```
new ObjectMapper.writeValuesToString(SQL);
```

However, this is impossible since it only converts an instantiated Object

Comment: Jackson serializes object fields. An enum class body is not a field.

Comment: The JSON example is pretty inclear. What's the purpose of duplicating the keys?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like you want by using Reflection. You can add simply method to your `SQL` class, which can return `Map`.

```
public static Map<String, ?> toJsonMap() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Class<?>[] declaredClasses = SQL.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    for (Class<?> clazz : declaredClasses) {
        if (clazz.isEnum()) {
            map.put(clazz.getSimpleName(), clazz.getEnumConstants());
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return Collections.singletonMap(SQL.class.getSimpleName(), map);
}
```

Simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(SQL.toJsonMap()));
```

Above program prints:

```
{
  "SQL" : {
    "Database" : [ "CREATE" ],
    "Table" : [ "CREATE", "ALTER" ]
  }
}
```